# jquery while php show hide

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<div class="commentfull">
    <?php $comment=m ysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE product = '$p'"); $user=m ysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user"); $datauser=m ysqli_fetch_assoc($user); while ($datacomment=m ysqli_fetch_assoc($comment)) { ?>
    <div class="commentcontent">
        <div class="commentfill">
            <?php echo $datacomment[ 'comment']; ?>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li class="commenttime">
                <p>
                    <?php echo $datacomment[ 'time']; ?>
                </p>
            </li>
            <li class="commentreply"><span id="triggerreply">Reply</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="commentformreply">
        <form method="POST" id="myform" action="<?php echo $base; ?>/config/addcomment.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="p" value="<?php echo $p; ?>" />
            <textarea class="commentarea" name="comment" placeholder="Your comment"></textarea><span class="commentclose">cancel</span>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

jquery :

```
$("#triggerreply").click(function() {
    $(".commentformreply").slideDown("medium");
});
$(".commentclose").click(function() {
    $(".commentformreply").slideUp("medium");
});
```

css :

```
.commentformreply {display:none; }
```

so, when i clicked 'reply' its show every commentformreply, i just want one of them appearing on its place where i clicked, how to doing this?

Comment: Does #triggerreply appear multiple times in the output.?

Comment: yes, its show commentbox for each while

Comment: You need to consider appending the primary key of table comments to the Div ID. for identification sakes. For this purpose alone KAD s solution is sufficient.

Comment: i just edit my question, i just try KAD solution, but its only the first one, how to doing for each of them?

Comment: You know it would be better if you give us the HTML generated rather than the PHP. Try going to view page source and post it into https://jsfiddle.net/ and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `closest()` to select the parent `.commentcontent` element and then with `next()`, select the next div (which is `.commentformreply` element):

**NOTE**

As KAD said, you must **not** produce more that one element with the same id. Instead, add a class (that's what they are for!)

```
$(".triggerreply").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.commentcontent').next().slideDown("medium");
});
$(".commentclose").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.commentformreply').slideUp("medium");   
});
```

**EXAMPLE (WORKING)**

Take a look at the following example. It works for multiple blocks of divs.

```js
$(".triggerreply").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.commentcontent').next().slideDown("medium");
});
$(".commentclose").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.commentformreply').slideUp("medium");   
});
```

```css
.commentformreply { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="commentfull">    
        <div class="commentcontent">
            <div class="commentfill">Comment</div>
            <ul>
                <li class="commenttime"><p>Time</p></li>
                <li class="commentreply"><span class="triggerreply">Reply</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="commentformreply">
            <form method="POST" id="myform" action="../config/addcomment.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="p" value="value>" />
                <textarea class="commentarea" name="comment" placeholder="Your comment"></textarea><span class="commentclose">cancel</span>    
            </form>
        </div>
  <div class="commentfull">    
        <div class="commentcontent">
            <div class="commentfill">Comment</div>
            <ul>
                <li class="commenttime"><p>Time</p></li>
                <li class="commentreply"><span class="triggerreply">Reply</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="commentformreply">
            <form method="POST" id="myform" action="../config/addcomment.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="p" value="value>" />
                <textarea class="commentarea" name="comment" placeholder="Your comment"></textarea><span class="commentclose">cancel</span>    
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks kapantzak, but its only working on first one. how to doing for each of them? my css : .commentformreply : display:none;

Comment: thank you so much kapantzak, so, i have to replace id into class. you are awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access triggerreply as an Id of the element since when the html is loaded dynamically, the ID is gonna conflict with other elements of the same ID since you are loading your data in a loop.

So its best used as a class then called as follows :

```
$(".triggerreply").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.commentcontent').next().slideDown("medium");
});
$(".commentclose").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.commentformreply').slideUp("medium");   
});
```